# Protractor click in ionic collection-view

Tags: protractor, ionic2, angular2-testing

i've tried to setup e2e testing in our ionic2/angular2 project by [clicker](https://github.com/lathonez/clicker/). Seems it was working but i faced the problem that click or tap doesn't work with collection-view items:

```html
let product = element(by.cssContainingText('.product-item', 'Produktserien'));
browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(product), TIMEOUT, 'Waiting for product item')
product.click();
browser.touchActions().tap(product).perform();
```

And i have to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` because with sync protractor begins to hang. 
Even with sleeps and waitForClickable it won't work. Mb did someone face with the same issue and is there some workaround how to get click worked? 
Other clicks on static elements like buttons works well. Seems protractor hangs when page with collection-view is open even with `ignoreSynchronization = true`

- Protractor: 4.0.13
- Browser: Chrome 54.0
- typescript: 2.0.6
- node: 6.9.2

```css
<collection-view-page class="ion-page show-page" style="z-index: 116;">
...
<inventory ng-reflect-products-list="" ng-reflect-categories-list="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"><div class="inventory-wrapper">
  <div class="scroll">
    <categories-tree ng-reflect-categories-list="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"><div class="products-holder">
  <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}-->
<!--template bindings={}-->
<div class="product-item" [ng-reflect-ng-style="[object](url) Object]" style="touch-action: pan-y; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); order: 0;">
      <div class="img-holder" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-color: rgb(156, 203, 129);">
        <!--template bindings={
            "ng-reflect-ng-if": null
            }-->
        <p class="item-placeholder">Produktserien</p>
        <span class="first-bg" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-color: rgb(156, 203, 129);"></span>
        <span class="second-bg" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-color: rgb(156, 203, 129);"></span>
      </div>
      <p class="item-name"><span>Produktserien</span></p>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Could you add a minimum repro case, component, template, and spec? I have no idea but will try to help if I can reproduce it.

Comment: Mb it's because of our own components, there is a sync with server every 5 sec and mb protractor assumes that angular is still working or some scripts always works in background. 
I made protractor work only with native selenium functions like `browser.driver.findElement(...)` but it's not convenient to use and we lose all protractor advantages. When using protractor's `element(..)` it hags and i get  jasmie_timeout